# How to publish Android Library to Maven Central Gradle 7.2.0

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I am trying to upload my first android library to Maven Central, but there is no proper documentation for Gradle 7.2.0 after some research I found some links but they are outdated too.

Things I have done till now:

- registered on jira
- approved my project on it and got access to nexus repository manager
- generated gpg key

now comes configuring the gradle file:
so i have followed this library = https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-maven-publish-plugin

1. in project root build.gradle file i have mentioned

```
    buildscript {
        dependencies {
             classpath 'com.vanniktech:gradle-maven-publish-plugin:0.20.0' // NEW
             classpath 'org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-gradle-plugin:1.4.10.2' // NEW
           }
       }
```

2. in library build.gradle i have added this plugin

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.library'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
        id 'com.vanniktech.maven.publish' // NEW
    }
```

3. in project root gradle.properties i have written this

```
SONATYPE_HOST=S01
RELEASE_SIGNING_ENABLED=true

GROUP=io.github.Darkprnce
POM_ARTIFACT_ID=InnerDrawer
VERSION_NAME=1.0.0

POM_NAME=InnerDrawer
POM_PACKAGING=aar

POM_DESCRIPTION=Inner Drawer is a highly customizable navigation drawer.
POM_INCEPTION_YEAR=2022

POM_URL=https://github.com/Darkprnce/InnerDrawer
POM_SCM_URL=https://github.com/Darkprnce/InnerDrawer
POM_SCM_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:Darkprnce/InnerDrawer.git
POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:Darkprnce/InnerDrawer.git

POM_LICENCE_NAME=MIT License
POM_LICENCE_URL=http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
POM_LICENCE_DIST=repo

POM_DEVELOPER_ID=Darkprnce
POM_DEVELOPER_NAME=Tarun Yadvendu
POM_DEVELOPER_URL=https://github.com/Darkprnce


signing.keyId=FCF8EDCA
signing.password=[my signing password]
signing.secretKeyRingFile=secret-keys.gpg
ossrhUsername=[my username]
ossrhPassword=[my password]
```

4. then again in library build.gradle i have mentioned publishing code

```
 publishing {
        repositories {
           maven {
              url = "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2"
              credentials {
                  username = ossrhUsername
                  password = ossrhPassword
               }
              }
             }
            }
```

now comes the issue when i run this command in terminal it gives wrong credentials error

```
* What went wrong:
Credentials required for this build could not be resolved.
> The following Gradle properties are missing for 'mavenCentral' credentials:
    - mavenCentralUsername
    - mavenCentralPassword
```

so if anyone has used this library then help me in this, library is well maintained so no issues in that i only want to know the right way to upload.

Comment: You need to specify `mavenCentralUsername` & `mavenCentralPassword` but you have `ossrhUsername` & `ossrhPassword` in your `gradle.properties` (old guide?).

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd i have uploaded it, a question will my username and password will be visible to others if i upload it like this, is there any way to hide it?

Comment: Just don't put those into files you upload to your GitHub repo. There can be a `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` on your local filesystem where it is safe to store such passwords.

Comment: To be clear, you shouldn't upload `signing.password` either.

Comment: isn't it needed for signing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245659/discussion-between-tarun-yadvendu-and-akarnokd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After [akarnokd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61158/akarnokd) help i was able to upload my library to Maven Central.
Step i have taken to resolve this issue:

1. First i have renamed the properties in project root => gradle.properties

ossrhUsername=[my username]  ==> mavenCentralUsername
ossrhPassword=[my password]  ==> mavenCentralPassword

2. Now the above information is available to everyone, as we have just mention our username and password in a gradle file which will be uploaded with the code. so to prevent that, [akarnokd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61158/akarnokd) suggested me to create a new gradle.properties file in C:/users/darkprnce/.gradle/gradle.properties and place the below information in that file :

```
mavenCentralUsername=[my username]
mavenCentralPassword=[my password]

signing.keyId=[last 8 digit of your key]
signing.password=[signing password]
signing.secretKeyRingFile=secring.gpg
```

3. we can remove publishing from library build.gradle file as it is already included in library.
4. run command

```
./gradlew publish --no-daemon --no-parallel
```

It will upload the library to Maven Central, then you can close the repository and release it.